# find characters between "quotes" from directory and convert lowercase to uppercase using shell

Tags: shell, conventions

I need a help to write a script for following condition.

1. Find all characters between "Double Quotes" from a directory recursively.
2. Convert from `lowercase` to `UPPERCASE` only the charactes between "Double Quotes", which we have searched in step 1.
3. Replace them in the same location of the file.

I tried with `grep`,`find` and `tr` but I am not able to find the solution needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of `sed` and `find` command and get your  exact result.

```
find  Dir_name  -exec sed -ri  's/(.*)(\".*\")(.*)/\1\U\2\E\3/g' 2>/dev/null {} \;

\U  -- Starting the conversion of upper case .
\E  -- Terminate the conversion of upper case .
```

Comment: Which output you got?

Comment: You are most welcome. You can accept it so that i will get a green tick